# How to scrape all pages of PDF in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-mining

I would like to scrape information in the first and second page of this pdf: https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/tables/2010-2018/state/asrh/PEPSR6H.pdf

I managed to obtain a (messy) dataframe from the first page's table but was unable to scrape the second page.

Here's the code that I use to obtain the dataframe from the first page:

```
library(tabulizer)
library(tidyverse)

link <- "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/tables/2010-2018/state/asrh/PEPSR6H.pdf"
df_page1 = extract_tables(link, output = "data.frame", header = FALSE)
```

I have no idea why the second page's table won't be able to be obtained. 
Can someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

You can get tables from all pages, including the second page, when you explicitly set `method="stream"`:

````r
library("tabulizer")
link <- "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/tables/2010-2018/state/asrh/PEPSR6H.pdf"
extract_tables(link, output = "data.frame", header = FALSE, method="stream")
#> [[1]]
#>                      V1        V2          V3          V4
#> 1                       Geography       Total            
#> 2                                                   White
#> 3                                                        
#> 4                                                        
#> 5         United States           308,745,538 241,937,061
#> 6               Alabama             4,779,736   3,362,877
#> 7                Alaska               710,231     483,873
#> 8               Arizona             6,392,017   5,418,483
#> 9              Arkansas             2,915,918   2,342,403
#> 10           California            37,253,956  27,636,403
#> 11             Colorado             5,029,196   4,450,623
#> 12          Connecticut             3,574,097   2,950,820
#> 13             Delaware               897,934     645,770
#> 14 District of Columbia               601,723     251,265
#> 15              Florida            18,801,310  14,808,867
#> 16              Georgia             9,687,653   6,144,931
#> 17               Hawaii             1,360,301     349,051
#> 18                Idaho             1,567,582   1,476,097
#> 19             Illinois            12,830,632  10,030,587
#> 20              Indiana             6,483,802   5,638,833
#> 21                 Iowa             3,046,355   2,839,615
#> 22               Kansas             2,853,118   2,501,057
#> 23             Kentucky             4,339,367   3,864,193
#> 24            Louisiana             4,533,372   2,902,875
#> 25                Maine             1,328,361   1,269,764
#> 26             Maryland             5,773,552   3,541,379
#> 27        Massachusetts             6,547,629   5,524,937
#> 28             Michigan             9,883,640   7,949,497
#> 29            Minnesota             5,303,925   4,623,461
#> 30          Mississippi             2,967,297   1,789,391
#> 31             Missouri             5,988,927   5,038,407
#> 32              Montana               989,415     891,529
#> 33             Nebraska             1,826,341   1,649,264
#> 34               Nevada             2,700,551   2,106,494
#> 35        New Hampshire             1,316,470   1,248,321
#> 36           New Jersey             8,791,894   6,546,498
#> 37           New Mexico             2,059,179   1,720,992
#> 38             New York            19,378,102  13,901,661
#> 39       North Carolina             9,535,483   6,898,296
#> 40         North Dakota               672,591     609,136
#> 41                 Ohio            11,536,504   9,664,524
#> 42             Oklahoma             3,751,351   2,851,510
#> 43               Oregon             3,831,074   3,403,252
#> 44         Pennsylvania            12,702,379  10,663,774
#>                                  V5         V6
#> 1                        Race Alone           
#> 2  Black or African American Indian      Asian
#> 3               American and Alaska           
#> 4                            Native           
#> 5              40,250,635 3,739,506 15,159,516
#> 6                  1,259,224 32,903     55,240
#> 7                    24,441 106,268     38,882
#> 8                   280,905 335,278    188,456
#> 9                    454,021 26,134     37,537
#> 10                2,486,549 622,107  5,038,123
#> 11                   214,919 78,144    144,819
#> 12                   392,131 16,734    140,516
#> 13                    196,281 5,929     29,342
#> 14                    310,379 3,264     21,705
#> 15                 3,078,067 89,119    474,199
#> 16                 2,993,927 48,599    323,459
#> 17                     22,473 4,960    531,633
#> 18                    10,950 25,782     20,034
#> 19                 1,903,458 73,846    604,399
#> 20                   603,797 24,487    105,535
#> 21                    91,695 13,563     54,232
#> 22                   173,298 33,044     69,628
#> 23                   342,804 12,105     50,177
#> 24                 1,462,969 33,037     71,829
#> 25                     16,269 8,771     13,783
#> 26                 1,731,513 30,885    326,655
#> 27                   504,365 29,944    359,673
#> 28                 1,416,067 68,396    243,062
#> 29                   280,949 67,325    217,792
#> 30                 1,103,101 16,837     26,477
#> 31                   700,178 30,595    100,213
#> 32                     4,215 63,495      6,379
#> 33                    85,971 23,418     33,322
#> 34                   231,224 42,965    203,478
#> 35                     16,365 3,530     28,933
#> 36                 1,282,005 49,907    746,212
#> 37                   49,006 208,890     31,253
#> 38                3,378,047 183,046  1,481,555
#> 39                2,088,362 147,566    215,952
#> 40                     8,248 36,948      7,032
#> 41                 1,426,861 29,674    196,693
#> 42                  284,332 335,664     67,126
#> 43                    74,414 66,784    145,009
#> 44                 1,431,826 39,735    358,195
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                V1        V2         V3         V4
#> 1                 Geography      Total           
#> 2                                           White
#> 3                                                
#> 4                                                
#> 5    Rhode Island            1,052,567    910,253
#> 6  South Carolina            4,625,364  3,164,143
#> 7    South Dakota              814,180    706,690
#> 8       Tennessee            6,346,105  5,056,311
#> 9           Texas           25,145,561 20,389,793
#> 10           Utah            2,763,885  2,547,329
#> 11        Vermont              625,741    598,592
#> 12       Virginia            8,001,024  5,725,432
#> 13     Washington            6,724,540  5,535,262
#> 14  West Virginia            1,852,994  1,746,513
#> 15      Wisconsin            5,686,986  5,036,923
#> 16        Wyoming              563,626    529,110
#>                                  V5        V6
#> 1                        Race Alone          
#> 2  Black or African American Indian     Asian
#> 3               American and Alaska          
#> 4                            Native          
#> 5                      75,073 9,173    31,768
#> 6                  1,302,865 24,665    61,247
#> 7                     10,533 72,782     7,775
#> 8                  1,068,010 26,256    93,897
#> 9                 3,070,440 251,209 1,000,473
#> 10                    33,864 40,729    57,800
#> 11                      6,456 2,308     8,069
#> 12                 1,579,414 41,525   449,149
#> 13                  252,333 122,649   491,685
#> 14                     63,885 3,975    12,637
#> 15                   367,021 60,100   131,828
#> 16                     5,135 14,457     4,649
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>                      V1        V2                V3          V4
#> 1                       Geography        Race Alone Two or More
#> 2                                                         Races
#> 3                                   Native Hawaiian            
#> 4                                 and Other Pacific            
#> 5                                          Islander            
#> 6         United States                     674,625   6,984,195
#> 7               Alabama                       5,208      64,284
#> 8                Alaska                       7,662      49,105
#> 9               Arizona                      16,112     152,783
#> 10             Arkansas                       6,685      49,138
#> 11           California                     181,431   1,289,343
#> 12             Colorado                       8,420     132,271
#> 13          Connecticut                       3,491      70,405
#> 14             Delaware                         690      19,922
#> 15 District of Columbia                         770      14,340
#> 16              Florida                      18,790     332,268
#> 17              Georgia                      10,454     166,283
#> 18               Hawaii                     138,292     313,892
#> 19                Idaho                       2,786      31,933
#> 20             Illinois                       7,436     210,906
#> 21              Indiana                       3,532     107,618
#> 22                 Iowa                       2,419      44,831
#> 23               Kansas                       2,864      73,227
#> 24             Kentucky                       3,199      66,889
#> 25            Louisiana                       2,588      60,074
#> 26                Maine                         377      19,397
#> 27             Maryland                       5,391     137,729
#> 28        Massachusetts                       5,971     122,739
#> 29             Michigan                       3,442     203,176
#> 30            Minnesota                       2,958     111,440
#> 31          Mississippi                       1,700      29,791
#> 32             Missouri                       7,178     112,356
#> 33              Montana                         734      23,063
#> 34             Nebraska                       2,061      32,305
#> 35               Nevada                      19,307      97,083
#> 36        New Hampshire                         532      18,789
#> 37           New Jersey                       7,731     159,541
#> 38           New Mexico                       3,132      45,906
#> 39             New York                      24,000     409,793
#> 40       North Carolina                      10,309     174,998
#> 41         North Dakota                         334      10,893
#> 42                 Ohio                       5,336     213,416
#> 43             Oklahoma                       5,354     207,365
#> 44               Oregon                      14,649     126,966
#> 45         Pennsylvania                       7,115     201,734
#> 46         Rhode Island                       1,602      24,698
#> 47       South Carolina                       3,957      68,487
#> 48         South Dakota                         517      15,883
#> 49            Tennessee                       5,426      96,205
#> 50                Texas                      31,242     402,404
#> 51                 Utah                      26,049      58,114
#> 52              Vermont                         175      10,141
#> 53             Virginia                       8,201     197,303
#> 54           Washington                      43,505     279,106
#> 55        West Virginia                         485      25,499
#> 56            Wisconsin                       2,505      88,609
#> 57              Wyoming    ``` r
library("tabulizer")
link <- "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/tables/2010-2018/state/asrh/PEPSR6H.pdf"
extract_tables(link, output = "data.frame", header = FALSE, method="stream")
#> [[1]]
#>                      V1        V2          V3          V4
#> 1                       Geography       Total            
#> 2                                                   White
#> 3                                                        
#> 4                                                        
#> 5         United States           308,745,538 241,937,061
#> 6               Alabama             4,779,736   3,362,877
#> 7                Alaska               710,231     483,873
#> 8               Arizona             6,392,017   5,418,483
#> 9              Arkansas             2,915,918   2,342,403
#> 10           California            37,253,956  27,636,403
#> 11             Colorado             5,029,196   4,450,623
#> 12          Connecticut             3,574,097   2,950,820
#> 13             Delaware               897,934     645,770
#> 14 District of Columbia               601,723     251,265
#> 15              Florida            18,801,310  14,808,867
#> 16              Georgia             9,687,653   6,144,931
#> 17               Hawaii             1,360,301     349,051
#> 18                Idaho             1,567,582   1,476,097
#> 19             Illinois            12,830,632  10,030,587
#> 20              Indiana             6,483,802   5,638,833
#> 21                 Iowa             3,046,355   2,839,615
#> 22               Kansas             2,853,118   2,501,057
#> 23             Kentucky             4,339,367   3,864,193
#> 24            Louisiana             4,533,372   2,902,875
#> 25                Maine             1,328,361   1,269,764
#> 26             Maryland             5,773,552   3,541,379
#> 27        Massachusetts             6,547,629   5,524,937
#> 28             Michigan             9,883,640   7,949,497
#> 29            Minnesota             5,303,925   4,623,461
#> 30          Mississippi             2,967,297   1,789,391
#> 31             Missouri             5,988,927   5,038,407
#> 32              Montana               989,415     891,529
#> 33             Nebraska             1,826,341   1,649,264
#> 34               Nevada             2,700,551   2,106,494
#> 35        New Hampshire             1,316,470   1,248,321
#> 36           New Jersey             8,791,894   6,546,498
#> 37           New Mexico             2,059,179   1,720,992
#> 38             New York            19,378,102  13,901,661
#> 39       North Carolina             9,535,483   6,898,296
#> 40         North Dakota               672,591     609,136
#> 41                 Ohio            11,536,504   9,664,524
#> 42             Oklahoma             3,751,351   2,851,510
#> 43               Oregon             3,831,074   3,403,252
#> 44         Pennsylvania            12,702,379  10,663,774
#>                                  V5         V6
#> 1                        Race Alone           
#> 2  Black or African American Indian      Asian
#> 3               American and Alaska           
#> 4                            Native           
#> 5              40,250,635 3,739,506 15,159,516
#> 6                  1,259,224 32,903     55,240
#> 7                    24,441 106,268     38,882
#> 8                   280,905 335,278    188,456
#> 9                    454,021 26,134     37,537
#> 10                2,486,549 622,107  5,038,123
#> 11                   214,919 78,144    144,819
#> 12                   392,131 16,734    140,516
#> 13                    196,281 5,929     29,342
#> 14                    310,379 3,264     21,705
#> 15                 3,078,067 89,119    474,199
#> 16                 2,993,927 48,599    323,459
#> 17                     22,473 4,960    531,633
#> 18                    10,950 25,782     20,034
#> 19                 1,903,458 73,846    604,399
#> 20                   603,797 24,487    105,535
#> 21                    91,695 13,563     54,232
#> 22                   173,298 33,044     69,628
#> 23                   342,804 12,105     50,177
#> 24                 1,462,969 33,037     71,829
#> 25                     16,269 8,771     13,783
#> 26                 1,731,513 30,885    326,655
#> 27                   504,365 29,944    359,673
#> 28                 1,416,067 68,396    243,062
#> 29                   280,949 67,325    217,792
#> 30                 1,103,101 16,837     26,477
#> 31                   700,178 30,595    100,213
#> 32                     4,215 63,495      6,379
#> 33                    85,971 23,418     33,322
#> 34                   231,224 42,965    203,478
#> 35                     16,365 3,530     28,933
#> 36                 1,282,005 49,907    746,212
#> 37                   49,006 208,890     31,253
#> 38                3,378,047 183,046  1,481,555
#> 39                2,088,362 147,566    215,952
#> 40                     8,248 36,948      7,032
#> 41                 1,426,861 29,674    196,693
#> 42                  284,332 335,664     67,126
#> 43                    74,414 66,784    145,009
#> 44                 1,431,826 39,735    358,195
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                V1        V2         V3         V4
#> 1                 Geography      Total           
#> 2                                           White
#> 3                                                
#> 4                                                
#> 5    Rhode Island            1,052,567    910,253
#> 6  South Carolina            4,625,364  3,164,143
#> 7    South Dakota              814,180    706,690
#> 8       Tennessee            6,346,105  5,056,311
#> 9           Texas           25,145,561 20,389,793
#> 10           Utah            2,763,885  2,547,329
#> 11        Vermont              625,741    598,592
#> 12       Virginia            8,001,024  5,725,432
#> 13     Washington            6,724,540  5,535,262
#> 14  West Virginia            1,852,994  1,746,513
#> 15      Wisconsin            5,686,986  5,036,923
#> 16        Wyoming              563,626    529,110
#>                                  V5        V6
#> 1                        Race Alone          
#> 2  Black or African American Indian     Asian
#> 3               American and Alaska          
#> 4                            Native          
#> 5                      75,073 9,173    31,768
#> 6                  1,302,865 24,665    61,247
#> 7                     10,533 72,782     7,775
#> 8                  1,068,010 26,256    93,897
#> 9                 3,070,440 251,209 1,000,473
#> 10                    33,864 40,729    57,800
#> 11                      6,456 2,308     8,069
#> 12                 1,579,414 41,525   449,149
#> 13                  252,333 122,649   491,685
#> 14                     63,885 3,975    12,637
#> 15                   367,021 60,100   131,828
#> 16                     5,135 14,457     4,649
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>                      V1        V2                V3          V4
#> 1                       Geography        Race Alone Two or More
#> 2                                                         Races
#> 3                                   Native Hawaiian            
#> 4                                 and Other Pacific            
#> 5                                          Islander            
#> 6         United States                     674,625   6,984,195
#> 7               Alabama                       5,208      64,284
#> 8                Alaska                       7,662      49,105
#> 9               Arizona                      16,112     152,783
#> 10             Arkansas                       6,685      49,138
#> 11           California                     181,431   1,289,343
#> 12             Colorado                       8,420     132,271
#> 13          Connecticut                       3,491      70,405
#> 14             Delaware                         690      19,922
#> 15 District of Columbia                         770      14,340
#> 16              Florida                      18,790     332,268
#> 17              Georgia                      10,454     166,283
#> 18               Hawaii                     138,292     313,892
#> 19                Idaho                       2,786      31,933
#> 20             Illinois                       7,436     210,906
#> 21              Indiana                       3,532     107,618
#> 22                 Iowa                       2,419      44,831
#> 23               Kansas                       2,864      73,227
#> 24             Kentucky                       3,199      66,889
#> 25            Louisiana                       2,588      60,074
#> 26                Maine                         377      19,397
#> 27             Maryland                       5,391     137,729
#> 28        Massachusetts                       5,971     122,739
#> 29             Michigan                       3,442     203,176
#> 30            Minnesota                       2,958     111,440
#> 31          Mississippi                       1,700      29,791
#> 32             Missouri                       7,178     112,356
#> 33              Montana                         734      23,063
#> 34             Nebraska                       2,061      32,305
#> 35               Nevada                      19,307      97,083
#> 36        New Hampshire                         532      18,789
#> 37           New Jersey                       7,731     159,541
#> 38           New Mexico                       3,132      45,906
#> 39             New York                      24,000     409,793
#> 40       North Carolina                      10,309     174,998
#> 41         North Dakota                         334      10,893
#> 42                 Ohio                       5,336     213,416
#> 43             Oklahoma                       5,354     207,365
#> 44               Oregon                      14,649     126,966
#> 45         Pennsylvania                       7,115     201,734
#> 46         Rhode Island                       1,602      24,698
#> 47       South Carolina                       3,957      68,487
#> 48         South Dakota                         517      15,883
#> 49            Tennessee                       5,426      96,205
#> 50                Texas                      31,242     402,404
#> 51                 Utah                      26,049      58,114
#> 52              Vermont                         175      10,141
#> 53             Virginia                       8,201     197,303
#> 54           Washington                      43,505     279,106
#> 55        West Virginia                         485      25,499
#> 56            Wisconsin                       2,505      88,609
#> 57              Wyoming                         521       9,754
````

<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>                     521       9,754

```
<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
```